# moving away from using BLOB to using referencing path

Tags: php, mysql

Instead of storing images using BLOB in mySQL, I have decided to attempt to use a referencing path instead. So I stored images into my "localhost" folder:

```
localhost/dvd_artwork/image.jpg
```

Therefore in my database, under column "dvdimage_path" I have TEXT "dvd_artwork/image.jpg" where my id = 1

However, I can't seem to get this to work at the moment

my catalog.php:

```
<img src="getImage.php?id=1" alt="" width="175" height="200" />
```

my getimage.php:

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];
// do some validation here to ensure id is safe

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("dvddb");
$sql = "SELECT dvdimage_path FROM dvd WHERE id=$id";
$result = mysql_query("$sql");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
mysql_close($link);

echo $row['dvdimage_path'];

?>
```

is there anything wrong?

Comment: `echo $row['dvdimage_path'];` will send just one line of `text/html` content to the browser where it was expecting `image/*` content type with binary data of the image.

Comment: I also suggest that you store minimum portion of the path. In your example, you should not store localhost in your database. Instead store it in a configuration file. Otherwise you will have problems when you move your site from `http://localhost` to `http://www.example.com`.

Comment: Salman is completely right.. you should set the headers to jpg: header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); and then: echo file_get_contents($row['dvdimage_path']);

Comment: @Salman after removing `echo $row['dvdimage_path'];` it still didnt work :/

Comment: @exxcellent: what do you see when you open the page `http://localhost/path/to/getImage.php?id=1`? If you see a string such as `localhost/dvd_artwork/image.jpg` then your script is right but your approach is wrong.

Comment: @SalmanA thanks for your input, i have removed localhost and now i can view my image using serpro's solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't make any sense – getImage returns a string, not an image...

You probably want to replace the getImage href, and just generate the page like this:

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];
// do some validation here to ensure id is safe

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("dvddb");
$sql = "SELECT dvdimage_path FROM dvd WHERE id=$id";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
mysql_close($link);

?>
<img src="<?= $row['dvdimage_path'] ?>" alt="" width="175" height="200" />
```

...or you want to use file_get_contents on the path, then echo that out with the appropriate headers:

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];
// do some validation here to ensure id is safe

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("dvddb");
$sql = "SELECT dvdimage_path FROM dvd WHERE id=$id";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
mysql_close($link);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); // Or png, or whatever...
echo file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$row['dvdimage_path']); // might need a slash between the two variables here...

?>
```

I'd recommend the first way if possible, as it then has the benefits of allowing normal header usage via your server config.

Comment: @rickbradshaw i just have a question with regards to your first way to handle this problem. so i did your method by putting the php code into the body of my catalog.php file but however i get an error of `Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\catalog.php on xxx` i think we are missing an `id` here.. where should this ID be?

Comment: Good point, you should either set it to say $id = 1, and change correspondingly, or remove it all together, (from query too), then loop through the result set to get all the images.

Answer (score 2):

remove quotes from mysql_query

```
// Change that
$result = mysql_query("$sql");

// To that
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: This makes no difference at-all. `"$sql"` and `$sql` are equivalent.

Comment: There's no point in parsing a single variabel in double quotes. This makes the parsing take longer time